# How to get start and end date and collapse continuous values - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

Hello I need help please, it seems so simple but I can't seem to get it right...this is currently my output below, I'm looking to make it look nicer by consolidating the continuous values. Filtering exact dates on my query would not work because I need to look at the events from a monthly basis to even a couple of months.

**date**    --------    **event**
05/20/22 ---        on
05/21/22 ---        on
05/22/22 ---    on
05/23/22    --- on
05/24/22    --- on
05/25/22    --- idle
05/26/22    --- on
05/27/22    --- on
05/28/22    --- idle
05/29/22    --- idle
05/30/22    --- off
05/31/22    --- off
06/01/22    --- idle
06/02/22    --- idle

Ideally, this is how I would like to make the output look

**start date**  --- **end date**    --- **event**
05/20/22    ----    05/24/22    ----        on
05/25/22    ----    05/25/22    ----        idle
05/26/22    ----        05/27/22    ----        on
05/28/22    ----        05/29/22    ----        idle
05/30/22    ----        05/31/22    ----        off
06/01/22    ----        06/02/22    ----        idle

Comment: The tags show Oracle 11g. Is that accurate? Is that your database version? Then - are all the consecutive dates present in your table, or might some dates be missing - and if so, how should that be handled in the output?

Comment: There will always be an event present everyday, the dates are just a small example of hundreds of rows that actually gets fetched especially if I'm looking at a few months worth

Answer (score 4):

For Oracle versions up to 11.2, the standard approach is the "fixed differences" or "tabibito san" method, illustrated below. The heart of the method is the creation of the additional grouping expression aliased as `grp` in the subquery.

```
with
  sample_data (event_date, event) as (
    select to_date('05/20/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'on'   from dual union all
    select to_date('05/21/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'on'   from dual union all
    select to_date('05/22/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'on'   from dual union all
    select to_date('05/23/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'on'   from dual union all
    select to_date('05/24/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'on'   from dual union all
    select to_date('05/25/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'idle' from dual union all
    select to_date('05/26/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'on'   from dual union all
    select to_date('05/27/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'on'   from dual union all
    select to_date('05/28/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'idle' from dual union all
    select to_date('05/29/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'idle' from dual union all
    select to_date('05/30/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'off'  from dual union all
    select to_date('05/31/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'off'  from dual union all
    select to_date('06/01/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'idle' from dual union all
    select to_date('06/02/22', 'mm/dd/rr'), 'idle' from dual
  )
-- end of sample data (for testing only); remove the WITH clause
-- and use your actual table and column names in the query below this line
select min(event_date) as start_date, max(event_date) as end_date, event
from   (
         select event_date, event,
                event_date - row_number() over (partition by event
                                                order by event_date) as grp
         from   sample_data
       )
group  by event, grp
order  by start_date
;
```

Output:

```
START_DATE END_DATE   EVENT
---------- ---------- -------
05/20/22   05/24/22   on  
05/25/22   05/25/22   idle
05/26/22   05/27/22   on  
05/28/22   05/29/22   idle
05/30/22   05/31/22   off 
06/01/22   06/02/22   idle
```

In Oracle 12.1 and later, the `match_recognize` clause does quick work of this assignment:

```
select start_date, end_date, event
from   sample_data
match_recognize(
  order    by event_date
  measures f.event as event, f.event_date as start_date,
           last(event_date) as end_date
  pattern  (f s*)
  define   s as event = f.event
);
```